# Tag in NLTK movie review corpus

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, tagged-corpus

I have the following code to print the 15 most common occurrences in the movie_review corpus.

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

documents =[]

for category in movie_reviews.categories():
    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category):
        documents.append((list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category))

random.shuffle(documents)

all_words =[]
for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words =nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
print(all_words.most_common(15))
```

I get the following output:

```
[(u',', 77717), (u'the', 76529), (u'.', 65876), (u'a', 38106), (u'and', 35576), (u'of', 34123), (u'to', 31937), (u"'", 30585), (u'is', 25195), (u'in', 21822), (u's', 18513), (u'"', 17612), (u'it', 16107), (u'that', 15924), (u'-', 15595)]
```

Why is the letter 'u' coming in the tags? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing quotes, commas and (on Python 2.7) the `u` prefix because you are passing a list of pairs to `print`. Printing individual strings works as expected. For example:

```
for word, cnt in all_words.most_common(15):
    print word, cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a [unicode strings in Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), nothing NLTK-specific.

Comment: Is there any way I can get just the letter and it's occurrence?